# Enter data into txtfield on javascript popup from vba

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am writing a macro in Excel. The macro needs to open a webbrowser, click a button,  enter a string in a textbox and click a new button.

The problem is that the textbox I need to enter the string in is in a popup window created from the first button. 
How do I get the textbox from the popup?
The first textbox I get this way:

```
frm.browser.Document.getElementById("theid")
```

The popup is created with JavaScript

```
newWindow = window.open('....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by going around it. 
In stead of dealing with the window I executed the JavaScript function that the popup was supposed to do, directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Window object you create with `.open`...

```
var newWindow = window.open('...

// Write some text in the new window
newWindow.document.getElementById("the-popup-id").value = '...
```